# Python xmlrpclib changes datetime object to DateTime instance on transmit

Tags: python, datetime, xml-rpc, python-datetime, xmlrpclib

Messages exchanged between a client and a server using the xmlrpclib using Python 2.6.x creates a type of 'instance' on server side instead of type 'datetime'. 
On the client side I create a new

```
updateTime = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
print type(updateTime)
print updateTime
```

results in

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
2015-10-07 10:21:52
```

when being send, the dictionary looks like this on the client side:

```
'updateTime': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 7, 10, 21, 52)
```

but the incoming dictionary on the server side looks like this:

```
'updateTime': <DateTime '20151007T10:21:52' at 7f4dbf4ceb90>
```

printing the type and its string representation looks like this:

```
<type 'instance'>
20151007T10:21:52
```

We are using xmlrpclib.ServerProxy but changing **use_datetime** either to *True* or *False* does not make any difference at all.

```
xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://'+rpc_server_addr, allow_none=True, use_datetime=True)
```

Why is this happening? I expected a tpye 'datetime.datetime' on the receiving side as well.

Comment: This is utterly insane. Why would they do this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert the xmlrpc.datetime format to a python datetime.datetime object.

The simplest way I have found to transform the object is:

```
import datetime

my_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(xmlrpc.datetime), '%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `use_builtin_types=True` works for me. All datetime values have type `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`.

Without this parameter all datetime were `<class 'xmlrpc.client.DateTime'>`

```
rpc = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://..../', use_builtin_types=True)
```

The [Python3 XML-RPC client documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html#xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy) says: 
The obsolete `use_datetime` flag is similar to `use_builtin_types` but it applies only to date/time values.